# When I use a web app that converts a bitmap to a vector, is the task run locally or in the cloud?

Tags: website

I found an interesting online bitmap-to-vector service provider called [Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home)

Who actually did the bitmap-to-vector conversion task? My local computer/CPU or the cloud-based service?

I wasn't prompted to install anything on machine.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't installed anything then it's likely that the image was uploaded to the server and processed there.

The `Download Result` button is also a good indication that the processing is done on the server.

Comment: Unless the conversion is done in JavaScript, but this is highly unlikely.

Comment: @Alex - I thought of adding that but decided it might only confuse the matter. It's also why I said "likely" :)